# Apothecary Symbols

Tags: symbols

[How do you make | Where are] the symbols for apothecary measures for ounce, drachm, and scruple using LaTeX?

[image: apothecary ounce]

[image: apothecary drachm]

[image: scruple]

Comment: There are Unicode code points for all three symbols so use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with a font that contains them.

Comment: What Alan said. ℥ (`U+2125`), ʒ (`U+0292`) and ℈ (`U+2108`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can load some unicode-font which has these symbols, e.g., [Lucida Sans Unicode](http://allfont.de/download/lucida-sans-unicode/), and use the symbols via `\char⟨unicode code point number⟩`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{Lucida Sans Unicode}

\begin{document}

OUNCE SIGN is at U+2125: \textsf{\char"2125}

drachm-symbol = LATIN SMALL LETTER EZH is at U+0292: \textsf{\char"0292}

SCRUPLE is at U+2108: \textsf{\char"2108}

pound = L B BAR SYMBOL is at U+2114 \textsf{\char"2114}

\end{document}
```

In case your operating-system/keyboard in use provide facilities for doing so you can also type these symbols directly, without using `\char`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks all!  It appears that I did not have a unicode font installed, so when I tried as above, it didn't work.  After installing the Lucida Sans Unicode font, I'm back in business!

Answer (score 6):

One freely available font containing these characters is the [Junicode](https://junicode.sourceforge.io/) font.  Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\begin{document}
Ounce: ℥

Drachm: Ȝ

Scruple: ℈
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]